Azure Logic App HTTP post action return error code 500
I have an existing API which I can call successfully using Postman Post. This is a simple API with basic authentication like following
Uri: http://api.internal.net/ws/rest/import/
Method: POST
Auth type: Basic Auth
Username: user
Password: xxxx
Body: raw
{
  "$content-type": "application/octet-stream",
  "$content": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}

Now I want to setup this request in Azure Logic App by adding a HTTP action (in-app), in Code view it is like following (the content is truncated). However, when this action runs, it return error code 500 InternalServerError.
{
  "type": "Http",
  "inputs": {
    "uri": "http://api.internal.net/ws/rest/import/",
    "method": "POST",
    "body": {
      "$content-type": "application/octet-stream",
      "$content": "Q0xNREZSIENOICAgQ0FOUE9URVggIDI0MTAwMzIyICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAg....DM0NiBIT1JORVBBWU4gT04gMTAgMDNFMjIyMyBFIEEgICAgMzEzMDIgU1lMVklURSAgIFNLIENOICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgCkVPTSAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAK"
    },    
    "authentication": {
      "type": "Basic",
      "username": "user",
      "password": "xxxx"
    },
    "retryPolicy": {
      "type": "none"
    }
  },
  "runAfter": {},
  "runtimeConfiguration": {
    "contentTransfer": {
      "transferMode": "Chunked"
    }
  }
}

What would cause this execution problem in Logic App? Is it because the request is incorrect format in Logic App? This is my first time using Logic App and I am so bad at this. Thank you in advance.
change different settings in Logic app workflow HTTP action but no luck.

The 500 error suggests your API code is throwing an unhandled exception. You need to share more information about that API; either the source code or some detailed error logs from it.

I do agree with @Andrew B that the issue should be with the API code, that is the server or function or code that is producing the response to the http call not the issue with http connector of logic app.
Make sure you provide correct method and authentication:

If the api provides a response correctly then :


Thank you. I found the problem at an initialize content object step that adding $ to json key. Use a Compose task to remove that extra $ character solves the problem.
enter image description here
